# How can multiple users writing to a file cause corruption?

Tags: php, file, corruption

I have made a chatroom that uses PHP to write to a text file, then the text file is read to the user. I have been told many times that if multiple users write to the same file on my server at the same time, the file could be corrupted.

How is this caused and how does this happen?

Comment: Hello. I recommend you take a look at [How to ask a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I read the page and I do not understand what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't connected to PHP, but to how files are stored on the drive and how they are read and written by the operating system.

Hard disk drivers bear some intelligence to optimize their own performance. But in the end, they're just stupid machines.

If an process (or two, or more) asks the OS to write a significant amount of data (a big post from user A) to a file, the driver may wish to break down this data into several chunks (matching the device's block size) to optimize HDD performance. Writing a chunk takes time. Even if it's a fraction of a second, it is still a duration, in which another process may show up and ask OS to write something else (a short greeting from user B) to the same file descriptor. The OS isn't intelligent enough to understand your application's intent, it just follows the instructions it issued. And writes user B's data. Then it proceeds to writing the next chunk of user A's data. Which results in the following data being stored in the file:

User A's post User A's post User A's post User A's post USER B'S QUICKY User A's post User A's post User A's post

This may look harmless at the first sight, but what if you drop in multibyte character encoding, for example? The end of user A's chunk may come in the middle of a character, which will render it illegible and barely restorable.